# Setup Project is not correctly registering assembly in GAC

Tags: .net-3.5, iis-7, url-rewriting, setup-project, gac

I have created a custom Rewrite Provider for IIS 7 following instructions in this article: [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module)

To simplify deployment, I have created a VS2010 Setup Project and configured it to deploy my assembly to GAC.

[image]

When I run the installer, it completes successfully, and **appears** to be registered the assembly in GAC (I have verified using *gacutil.exe /l*).

However, when I go to IIS Manager to register the new rewrite provider it is not displayed in the list of available providers.

I have also tried to install the assembly manually using *gacutil.exe /if*. This does work and makes assembly visible in the list of available providers in IIS Manager.

Am I missing some sort of configuration in my Setup Project?

Comment: How did you configure your project to install the assembly in GAC?

Comment: By adding a Global Assembly Cache Folder and adding output from my IIS Rewrite Provider project to that

Comment: Everything looks right to me as far as they advertise how it should work, have you considered a custom action and call gacutil directly yourself.

Comment: strong name may be a problem have u make sure that???

Comment: @ShaunWilde I cannot call `gacutil` directly. The reason I am using Setup Project is to avoid having dependency on `gacutil`, so that my custom provider can be installed on servers that do not have an SDK installed.

Comment: @amod0017 Strong name is not an issue. The assembly is signed. Manual installation using `gacutil` works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue (provider not showing up) after I GACed my provider by hand. In my case, dropping the framework version on myu project from 4.0 to 3.5 did the trick.